# I had an issue with the mobile app in D365 F&O

Tags: dynamic, azure-mobile-services, dynamic365

I am working on a mobile app in Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations (D365 F&O). I have built my first app, but I encountered several issues:

1- ComboBox Issue: The ComboBox does not allow me to select an item from the list even though it appears. I am unable to choose any item.

2-Data Not Appearing in Mobile Search: When I add data to the system, it gets saved successfully. However, when I search for it using my phone, it does not appear. However, when I check using a browser, I can see that the data is already saved.

3- Slow Data Loading: Sometimes, the loading of data takes a long time, and it can even take hours. I'm unsure if this is due to the speed of my internet connection or if there is another underlying issue.